# Chrome don't load properly google font

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts

I developed a site around a few months ago. The site uses as basic font the Open Sans and as secondary the GFS Neohellenic. Both are being loaded from google fonts. I just noticed that only in Chrome, version 37,38 maybe 36 the second font don't load properly and fallsback.

If I go to Developer Tools and select the html entity that has this font as property and change the font-family to the same font name, GFS Neohellenic, the font is being loaded properly.

Site : http://everymatic.com/

A possible solution would be to load the font on the server. Is any other solution to this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I change the following css rule

font-family: 'GFS Neohellenic', sans-serif;

to

font-family: 'GFS Neohellenic';

and the problem was fixed.

I don't know why the first rule was working for months and with the last chrome updates wasn't.